# Null space in ordinary differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been watching [some videos on linear algebra on OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/index.htm), and alternating between thinking I "get" nullspace, and not knowing what's going on at all.

Just now however, I did a problem set with the question:

$\text{Find the general solution of the differential equation:}$
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dx}-2y=e^{3x} $$

Nothing difficult about that, the actual question's irrelevant, but coming to (at least what I hope is!) the solution:

$$y=C_1\cdot e^{-x}+C_2\cdot e^{2x} +\dfrac{1}{5}e^{3x}$$

made me think - is the analogue here that the complementary part of $y$ effectively the nullspace of $y$? The particular solution $y_p=\dfrac{1}{5}e^{3x}$ is valid in its own right, but remains valid with any multiples $C_1, C_2$ of the free variables in the nullspace?

---

Did I have a sudden moment of understanding, or does the above sound totally confused?

Comment: Looks like illumination to me!

Comment: Oh my god, and just standard integration too?! Math is so cool.

Comment: Man oh man is that ever god's own truth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the operator $(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{d}{dx}-2)$ then the set of homogeneous solutions is the null space of this operator.

Comment: I get it! Thanks! I always sort of, knew how to solve the equations but dind't really have a full understanding of *why* I was following those steps.

Comment: So in general, 'null space' can be summarised as 'the subspace consisting of all the solutions for zero' (which of course will always include the zero vector)?

Comment: Correct! As long as things are linear, if you have a non linear operator, it may not map zero to zero :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say 'operator' please? When I hear 'operator', I think of $+$, $\cdot$, or $^T$ - I'm not sure I understand the sense in which $D_x^2 - D_x - 2$ is an operator? My other line of thought, which is perhaps the answer to aforementioned question, is how is the path to solving this ODE expressed entirely as matrix/vector? Is it $Ay=0$, where $A$ is the ODE, and $y$ the general solution?

Comment: Okay, an operator is a mapping from one space to another, in this case, we have a differential operator, it maps functions to functions. In this example, all we require is that the set of functions we map from (ie our domain) are twice continuously differentiable. It is important to note that function are infinite dimensional vectors, and operators can be thought of as infinite dimensional matrices.

Comment: When it states the operator (lets call it $T$), $T=D_x^2-D_x-2$. We have $T:C^2\to C^2$ where $T(y)=D_x^2y-D_xy-2y$. Then the null space is the set of all functions, that it maps to $0$, I.e all homogeneous general solutions.

Comment: Ah! So you could say $(D_x^2 - D_x - 2) : (y_h+y_c) \mapsto 0$? (Edit: you beat me to the punch, and seems I was wrong)

Comment: What you say is close, but if we were to map something that was not a solution, then it would not be mapped to zero.

Comment: So, in general, to solve $T = f(x)$, we find $y_h$ such that $T:y_h\mapsto 0$, and $y_p$ such that $T:y_p\mapsto f(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789665/null-space-in-ordinary-differential-equations/789784?noredirect=1#comment1637360_789784) any longer, but I meant $y_p$ *not* $y_c$. Typo caused by mixmatch of $y_c, y_h$ in texts.. d'oh.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to include boundary conditions, i.e. we consider the ODE on $[0,1]$ where $y(0)=y(1)=0$, then we consider the space $Y=\{y\in C^2[0,1]:y(0)=y(1)=0\}$ and we consider $T:Y\to C^2[0,1]$