# Null Space of a Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, linear-transformations

I am studying the differential equations section of Calc 2 — Homogeneous Linear 2nd Order O.D.Es with constant coefficients (what a mouthful).

The example given is $y''+2y'-8y=0$, with general solution $y(x)=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-4x}$.

I was introduced to the idea that differentiation is a linear transformation in my linear algebra course. If we take the differential equation, $y''+2y'-8y$ to be our linear transformation, does that mean that the general solution, $y(x)$, is our nullspace? Furthermore, could we say that a basis for our nullspace is the vectors $e^{2x}$ and $e^{-4x}$.

My course mentions nothing about this, but the ideas feel similar. Could anyone provide some insight into if these seemingly separate topics of study are connected? Any further reading on this link would be great.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The linear transformation is not the equation itself, but instead the mapping sending the function $y$ to $y'' + 2y' - 8y$. A candidate space for the domain of the transformation could be twice-differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. The nullspace is the set of solutions to the equation you specify. The "general solution" identifies the nullspace as a function space spanned by $e^{2x}$ and $e^{-4x}$. It is hard to recommend a good first book without context; a lot of books that go deeply into linear algebra do not go deep into differential equations, or vice versa.

Comment: You may want to look [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/diffeqdim.pdf) Keith Conrad's paper.

Comment: @leslietownes thankyou, this has helped me clarify my thoughts on this

Comment: @azif00 very interesting... may be too complex to completely understand but shall give it a go

Comment: Related [What is the relation between general solution of a differential equation and null space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2759934/152568); [Null space in ordinary differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789665/152568); [How are eigenvectors/eigenvalues and differential equations connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10443/152568)

Comment: @azif00 that is a great paper! Thanks for bringing it up!